# Zsh, paste content of variable into the prompt

Tags: zsh

For my work I have a small helper script that loads a url into a variable:

getUrl.zsh;

`url=$"(php getUrl.php $1)"`

which i call using an alias:

`alias geturl="source getUrl.zsh"`

Sometimes the urls stop working and I need to edit them, say add https, and it would be very handy if I somehow could replace the variable url with its content:

`curl $url  => curl 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

It feels like it should be possible somehow

Comment: By default `zsh`'s **Tab**-completion expands variables, if the cursor is placed right after the variable name, e.g. `curl $url█`, where `█` is the placement of the cursor. Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, that is awesome, thank you! please supply it as an answer so i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default zsh's <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion expands variables, if the cursor is placed right after the variable name, e.g.

```
curl $url█
```

where `█` is the placement of the cursor. Note, that it usually does not work, if the cursor is placed within the variable name.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `expand-word` widget, which is by default bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd> (That is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>*</kbd>) in *Emacs*-mode. If you are using *Vi*-mode you can bind it with the `bindkey` command:

```
bindkey "^X*" expand-word
```

With `expand-word`, the cursor can be placed just after the variable as well as anywhere on the variable name.